# GCP remote-builder should create VM with External IP in certain ranges

Tags: google-cloud-build

GCP remote-builder should create VM with External IP in certain ranges. For example 49.70.30.100 to 49.70.30.150

Inside remote builder, VM instance is creating with a random external IP but I want to be in the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't restrict an ephemeral external IP assignation to a specific range (the 51 addresses in your example range may be already in use somewhere else at the time you launch your build).

Having said that, you can [reserve a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) that will be reserved for your project, whether it's in use or not, and assign it to your remote-builder VM with the `--address` [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--address) as `INSTANCE_ARGS`.

Note that you'll be [billed for the IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing#ipaddress) reservation (from January 1st, 2020, whether it's in use or not)

Comment: ya I tried it, Its working but, If I want to build other images simultaneously  both VM will have same IP

Comment: Indeed, if you want to have _n_ VMs running concurrently, you'll need to reserve _n_ static external IPs. Following [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/blob/master/remote-builder/examples/cloudbuild.yaml), you'll have one build step per VM, so you can set different IPs for each.